# How to systematically avoid unsafe pattern matching in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

Consider the following broken function:

```
def sum (list : Seq[Int]) : Int = list match {
  case Nil => 0
  case head :: tail => head + sum(tail)
}
```

Here, the function was supposed to work with a `List[Int]`, but was refactored to accept `Seq[Int]` instead, thus becoming broken without the compiler noticing.

This gaping hole in Scala's incomplete pattern match detection makes it next to useless.

I want to have a way of systematically detecting such problems. Specifically, I'd like the compiler to emit an error/warning on every `instanceof`-guided pattern match, i.e. I only want to allow pattern matches on sealed hierarchies and on custom matchers.

Are there existing compiler options/plugins for doing conservative (as opposed to arbitrary) checks of pattern matching safety?

Comment: I use this match example with `List` very often, too. My advice in this case is to use `list.toList match ...`(because you know in advance you probably will refactor some code (perhaps not this method) later on and the match cases are only working with `List`), then you can refactor the method parameter to `Seq` without broken code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389400/108915) by M. Odersky.

#### Summary

Checks on matches of non-sealed hierarchies are doable, not trivial and not (yet) implemented.

Comment: That misses the point. I don't ask the compiler to be omniscient or even clever. I just want the check to become conservative, meaning that out of "Safe / Unsafe / Unknown" analyses only the first one would be admitted without warnings.

Answer (score 3):

`Nil` and `::` are clearly ways to construct a `List`, but not all `Seq`uences happen to be `Lists`, so one would expect the Scala type checker to reject this program as ill-typed. Right?

Wrong. Try this and you'll see what I mean:

```
def sum (list : Seq[Int]) : Int = list match {
  case Nil => 0
  case head :: tail => head + sum(tail)
  case _ => -1
}

> sum(Array(1,2,3).toSeq)
res1: Int = -1
> sum(List(1,2,3))
res2: Int = 6
```

So you see, *some* `Seq`uences *might* be able to be deconstructed with `Nil` and `::`, so those which can, will. Those which can't will fail the pattern match and move on, trying the next match. `Nil` and `::` are sufficient to cover all the possibilities for `List`, but not for `Seq`. There is a tradeoff here between subtyping, convenience, and type safety. The solution for now is: be more careful when you refactor.